# Finishing File Class

Tags: java, file, tokenize

I keep getting an error telling me lineNumber cannot be resolved to a variable? I'm not really sure how to fix this exactly. Am I not importing a certain file to java that helps with this?

And also how would I count the number of chars with spaces and without spaces.

Also I need a method to count unique words but I'm not really sure what unique words are.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LineWordChar {
public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Convert our text file to string
String text = new Scanner( new File("way to your file"), "UTF-8" ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("way to your file"));
String lines="";
int linesi=0;
int words=0;
int chars=0;
String s="";

// while next lines are present in file int linesi will add 1
    while ((lines=bf.readLine())!=null){
    linesi++;}
// Tokenizer separate our big string "Text" to little string and count them
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(text);
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
    s = st.nextToken();
      words++;
// We take every word during separation and count number of char in this words    
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
          chars++;}
    }
 System.out.println("Number of lines: "+linesi);
 System.out.println("Number of words: "+words);
 System.out.print("Number of chars: "+chars);
}
}
 abstract class WordCount {

/**
 * @return HashMap a map containing the Character count, Word count and
 *         Sentence count
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 *
 */
public static void main() throws FileNotFoundException {
    lineNumber=2; // as u want
    File f = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    f = new File("file_stats.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    int totalLines=0;
    int totalWords=0;
    int totalChars=0;
    int totalSentences=0;
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        totalLines++;
        if(totalLines==lineNumber){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            totalChars += line.length();
            totalWords += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();  //line.split("\\s").length;
            totalSentences += line.split("\\.").length;
            break;
        }
        sc.nextLine();

    }

    list.add(totalChars);
    list.add(totalWords);
    list.add(totalSentences);
    System.out.println(lineNumber+";"+totalWords+";"+totalChars+";"+totalSentences);

}
}
```

Comment: post the exact error message, and please try to restrict your question to one single problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your code running you have to do at least two changes:

Replace:

```
lineNumber=2; // as u want
```

with

```
int lineNumber=2; // as u want
```

Also, you need to modify your `main` method, you can not throw an exception in your `main` method declaration because there is nothing above it to catch the exception, you have to handle exceptions inside it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Convert our text file to string
        try {
            String text = new Scanner(new File("way to your file"), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("way to your file"));
            String lines = "";
            int linesi = 0;
            int words = 0;
            int chars = 0;
            String s = "";

            // while next lines are present in file int linesi will add 1
            while ((lines = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                linesi++;
            }
            // Tokenizer separate our big string "Text" to little string and count them
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                s = st.nextToken();
                words++;
                // We take every word during separation and count number of char in this words
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    chars++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of lines: " + linesi);
            System.out.println("Number of words: " + words);
            System.out.print("Number of chars: " + chars);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've used a global `Exception` catch, you can separate expetion in several catches, in order to handle them separatedly. It gives me an exception telling me an obvious `FileNotFoundException`, besides of that your code runs now.

Comment: what would i need to add to it to count the char with spaces and without spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: basically to count the spaces in between the text in a file.

Comment: I guess that is another question

Comment: A simple way to count the words in a string could be `string.length() - string.replaceAll(" ", "").length()`

Comment: on what part of my code would i add that to exactly?

Comment: that will return an integer... use it when you need to count the number of words

Answer (score 0):

lineNumber variable should be declared with datatype.

> int lineNumber=2; // as u want

change the first line in the main method from just lineNumber to **int lineNumber = 2** by setting its data type, as it is important to set data type of every variable in Java.